# How to consume a message on server side from websocket client (browser)?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I just set a websocket connection, and I want to send a message from browser to server.

I used `connect()` method to send message. But I don't know how to consume it at server-side. Here is what I have done at client side.

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket/test);
var message = 'A message to send';
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
stompClient.send('/app/hello',{},message);
```

I expected to get the message sent in the server console and store it in an object.

Comment: What STOMP broker are you using? What kind of consumer are you using? What do you mean by "get the message sent in the server console"?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram
 I'm using sockjs, stomp over Websocket. In my backend code I have a method who take some data as argument (ID) and this data is send by the user on the browser. So after sending data to the backend my concern is to know how to get it and use it in the backend. Which annotations, methods should I use on spring Boot. Sorry I'm new with Websockets

Comment: You should clarify your question and explain that your server-side app is using Spring Boot. Although the question is using `spring-boot` tag you don't mention Spring Boot anywhere in your question which is confusing. Also, I recommend you take a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/. It should help.